# Regular expression for not extracting those with spacing

Tags: python, regex

```
RangersIslandersDevils
KingDucks
Sharks
Blackhawks
Red Wings
```

How do I extract the following using regex?

```
Rangers
Islanders
Devils
Kings
Ducks
Sharks
Blackhawks
Red Wings
```

Basically those with spacing remains the same.

Patterns that I have tried that don't work:

```
[A-Z][a-z]+[^\s]
[A-Z][a-z]+[^\s]$
[A-Z][a-z]+[\s][A-Z][a-z]+|[A-Z][a-z]+
```

THANKS ALL I GOT IT!

Comment: In what way do the patterns you have tried not work?

Comment: `re.split(r'(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])', team)`

Answer (score 0):

I think this pattern will match the Red Wings
`[A-Z][a-z]+( [A-Z][a-z]+)?`

Comment: hi thanks for the help! but i got this instead 

[('Rangers', ''), ('Islanders', ''), ('Devils', ''), ('King', ''), ('Ducks', ''), ('Sharks', ''), ('Blackhawks', ''), ('Red Wings', ' Wings')]

Comment: Then you're done right?  Just build the list from the first match object and ignore the second one.